# Redis: How to store a set of strings and an associated timestamp (in seconds)?

Tags: redis

I want to associate a list of string values with a timestamp. For example:

```
1639477421.7408276 - "string_value_1", "string_value_2", "string_value_3"
```

Later, I want to pass a timestamp range to get all associated string values whose timestamp is in the range.

I once tried to create a set where the key would be the timestamp and the values would be the strings themselves, but searching by key as a timestamp would hardly be possible.

1. How to store such a data structure?
2. How to select values using the specified timestamp range?

Comment: Did you check Redis Streams? https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro

Comment: If you want to search by range, you should try sorted set.

Comment: Check out Redis TimeSeries module https://oss.redis.com/redistimeseries/